# parallel run for genetic algorithm

Tags: parallel-processing, genetic-algorithm

I have GA, a `for` loop which runs generations, and in this `for` I have `while` which is replacing old individuals with new and better one, how can I parallelize this? I found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761646/algorithm-to-optimize-threads-used-in-a-calculation) , they say i should divide in to smaller parts, but what would this part be ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is usually the case that the vast majority of the computational effort in a genetic algorithm is involved in evaluating the fitness of each individual in the population. It is also usually the case that the fitness evaluation of each individual does not depend on any of the other individuals in the current generation of the population.

Therefore, the typical parallelization approach is to evaluate the fitness of multiple individuals within a generation in parallel.

You can also easily parallelize the creation of new individuals when moving from one generation to the next. Each individual can pick its parents and perform the crossover and mutation steps in parallel with all other individuals.

I will also note that in many cases you will find that you want to run the evolution multiple times (either with different initial conditions or different parameter settings). Of course, you can just run the non-parallelized GA instances in parallel.